# Phalcon PHP error while insert data (after edding FROM_UNIXTIME)

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I'm writting a restful api on php using Phalcon. As DB I'm using MySQL.
When I added `FROM_UNIXTIME()`I started to get error;

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO readings (sensor_id, value, error, timestamp) VALUES (:sensor_id:, :value:, :error:, FROM_UNIXTIME( :timestamp: ));";

    $status = $app->modelsManager->executeQuery($query, array(
        'sensor_id' =>$reading->sensor_id,
        'value' => $reading->value,
        'error' => $reading->error,
        'timestamp' => $reading->timestamp
    ));
```

Error:

> [Sun Jul 19 17:10:19.895081 2015] [:error] [pid 24057] [client 46.39.49.135:49183] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception' with message 'Scanning error before '' when parsing: INSERT INTO readings (sensor_id, value, error, timestamp) VALUES (:sensor_id:, :value:, :error:, FROM_UNIXTIME( :timestamp: )); (127)' in /var/www/rest.technical-craft.ru/public/index.php:42\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query->parse()\n#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query->execute()\n#2 /var/www/rest.technical-craft.ru/public/index.php(42): Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manager->executeQuery('INSERT INTO rea...', Array)\n#3 [internal function]: {closure}()\n#4 /var/www/rest.technical-craft.ru/public/index.php(67): Phalcon\Mvc\Micro->handle()\n#5 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/rest.technical-craft.ru/public/index.php on line 42